# How can i fix the Error Code: 1318 in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I CREATED TWO same FUNCTION without the function name

```
 DELIMITER //
 CREATE FUNCTION fnc_credit_custstatus(custcredit INT)
 RETURNS VARCHAR(6) DETERMINISTIC
 BEGIN
 DECLARE custstatus VARCHAR(6);
 IF CustCredit>=1000 THEN SET custstatus='VIP';
 ELSEIF CustCredit<1000 THEN SET custstatus='NONVIP';
 END IF;
 RETURN (custstatus);
 END//
 DELIMITER ;
```

and the other one is :

```
 DELIMITER //
 CREATE FUNCTION f(custcredit INT)
 RETURNS VARCHAR(6) DETERMINISTIC
 BEGIN
 DECLARE custstatus VARCHAR(6);
 IF CustCredit>=1000 THEN SET custstatus='VIP';
 ELSEIF CustCredit<1000 THEN SET custstatus='NONVIP';
 END IF;
 RETURN (custstatus);
 END//
 DELIMITER ;
```

This two function are all exists
but when I want to select the same query with different name,

```
  SELECT *,fnc_credit_custstatus(custcredit)AS custstatus FROM customer_salon; 


 SELECT *, f(custcredit) AS custstatus FROM customer_salon;
```

BUT the longer name one can't run out

```
 Error Code: 1318
 Incorrect number of arguments for FUNCTION database.fnc_credit_custstatus; expected 0, got 1`
```

I don't know why

Comment: Delete the function and create it a new, and restrat the mysql database. You should also check the error log for any clues

Comment: Try dropping your function before creating.